# Less verbose debug screen in Catalyst?

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit

in my stage server I would like to activate the debug so the clients can find errors for themselves before the app goes to the production server.

**BUT I only want the first part of the message, not the Request, or the Session Data.**

For example: Couldn't render template "templates/home.tt2: file error - templates/inc/heater: not found".

The message is enough for me and for my client to see that the "header" call is misspelled.

The Request has a lot of irrelevant information for the client, but also has A LOT of internal developing information that should be hidden all the time!!

Regards

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to override Catalyst's [`dump_these`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst#%24c-%3Edump_these) method. This returns a list of things to display on Catalyst's error debugging page.

The default implementation looks like:

```
sub dump_these {
    my $c = shift;
    [ Request => $c->req ],
    [ Response => $c->res ],
    [ Stash => $c->stash ],
    [ Config => $c->config ];
}
```

but you can make it more restrictive, for example

```
sub dump_these {
    my $c = shift;
    return [ Apology => "We're sorry that you encountered a problem" ],
           [ Response => substr($c->res->body, 0, 512) ];
}
```

You would define `dump_these` in your app's main module -- the one where you `use Catalyst`.

Comment: Great!, but in the usual MyApp.pm file, after the "use Catalyst..." all I have are package configurations, like __PACKAGE__->config( encoding => 'UTF-8' )  So I do not know how to insert here a subroutine. I tried to paste the code as it is, just in case it rings the bell, but it doesn't work.

Comment: That should be right. Then you'd want `dump_these` defined in the `MyApp` package. If you're not sure what package this method belongs in, and you can tolerate a `Subroutine redefined ...` warning, you could also define it like `sub Catalyst::dump_these { ... }`.

Comment: Hi, @mob,I tried again. Now I can remove the Stash and the Config blocks. I can add blocks like your "Apology" suggestion. But If I remove (or just change) Response, the debug screen appears, but in the console I get an exception in engine `Can't call method "status" on an undefined value...`. If I remove the Request block i get a total crash exception, with no screen and `Can't call method "method"...`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hmmmmm. The `log_request` and `log_response` methods in Catalyst also use `dump_these` and expect to get back values for `Request` and `Response`.  Next suggestion: hack the `finalize_error` or `_dump_error_page_element` methods in the `Catalyst::Engine` module.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem that I solved by overriding the Catalyst method `log_request_parameters`.

Something like this (as @mob said, put it in your main module):

```
sub log_request_parameters {
    my $c          = shift;
    my %all_params = @_; 

    my $copy = Clone::clone(\%all_params);  # don't change the 'real' request params

    # Then, do anything you want to only print what matters to you,
    # for example, to hide some POST parameters:
    my $body = $copy->{body} || {}; 
    foreach my $key (keys %$body) {
        $body->{$key} = '****' if $key =~ /password/;
    }

    return $c->SUPER::log_request_parameters( %$copy );
}
```

But you could also simply return at the beginning, if you don't want any GET/POST parameters displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't think of the more obvious solution, in your case: you could simply set your log level to something higher than `debug`, which would prevent these `debug` logs from being displayed, but would keep the `error` logs:

```perl
    # (or a similar condition to check you are not on the production server)
    if ( !__PACKAGE__->config->{dev} ) {
        __PACKAGE__->log->levels( 'warn', 'error', 'fatal' ) if ref __PACKAGE__->log;
    }
```